# How do I remove the white lines beside each TabItem?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've recently taken to learning WPF for a project. I've been styling a `TabControl` to fit the colors of a component library I'm using, but these strange white lines have appeared beside each `TabItem`, but only between items or before the first item.

What are they, and how can I get rid of them? I tried using the inspector provided in Visual Studio but they aren't selectable, which leads me to believe they are some internal part of `TabItem`, but I'm stuck at this point.

[image: | Story | Test | Test - the vertical bars are white]

Usage:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1"
            TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
            BorderBrush="#00000000"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Resources="{StaticResource TabControlResources}">
    <TabItem Header="Story">
        <local:Workspace />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Test">
        Test Tab
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Test">
        Test Tab 2
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

And style definition:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="TabControlResources">
    <Style TargetType="TabControl">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{StaticResource Fluent.Ribbon.Brushes.RibbonTabControl.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{StaticResource Fluent.Ribbon.Brushes.IdealForegroundColorBrush}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{StaticResource Fluent.Ribbon.Brushes.IdealForegroundColorBrush}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource Fluent.Ribbon.Brushes.RibbonTabControl.Background}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource Fluent.Ribbon.Brushes.RibbonTabItem.Active.Background}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are part of the TabItem. You can add the setter in the tab item style within your resource which should do the job:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

And the result will be such:

[image]

**Alternatively:**

You can completely remove it, but unfortunately it is part of the template and the template has to be modified:

[image]

In Visual studio designer right click on one of the tab items and go to "Edit template" then "Edit a copy".

```
 <Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
          <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <Border x:Name="mainBorder" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
                    <Border x:Name="innerBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}" Margin="-1" Opacity="0"/>
               </Border>
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
          </Grid>
```

In there you have to modify the `BorderThichness` of `mainBorder` and `innerBoarder` to `BorderThickness="0"`

Result:

[image]