# Add clear button to WPF DatePicker from style

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I able to add clear button to calender's control on DatePicker , but i wonder is it posible to add the same on DatePicker Text box ?

What i have :
[image]

What i trying to get : 
[image]

```
<DatePicker >
                <DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Calendar">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue">
                                            <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem" 
                                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                                      Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarItemStyle}" 
                                                      Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
                                            <Button Content="Clear Date"  Click="Button_Click"
                                                x:Name="PART_ClearButton"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                Margin="2"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
            </DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [DatePicker Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datepicker-styles-and-templates).

Modify the PART_Root:

Look at the comments in the code, modified part is indicated!

```
 <Grid x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <!--ADD ANOTHER COLUMN HERE-->
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <!--CHANGE COLUMN=1 TO COLUMN =2-->
                            <Button x:Name="PART_Button"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                Focusable="False"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="3,0,3,0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Style="{StaticResource DropDownButtonStyle}"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                            <!--//ADD THE BUTTON HERE-->
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="X" Foreground="Red" Width="20" Height="20"/>

                            <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                           Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}"
                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
              Grid.Column="0"
              IsHitTestVisible="False"
              Opacity="0"
              Grid.Row="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                     Fill="#A5FFFFFF"
                     RadiusY="1"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     RadiusX="1" />
                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1"
                     Fill="#A5FFFFFF"
                     Height="18"
                     Margin="3,0,3,0"
                     RadiusY="1"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     RadiusX="1"
                     Width="19" />
                                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
                 AllowsTransparency="True"
                 Placement="Bottom"
                 PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}"
                 StaysOpen="False" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
```

Result will be:

[image]

Comment: When i apply this style  calendar button image is gone.

Comment: did you copy everything from the MSDN page ? The Calendar button is part of the DropDownButtonStyle.

Comment: Alternatively you can create a copy of the template instead of copying it from  the page. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61341064/2289942 for how to create a copy